# Excel - Microsoft Query - SQL Server login - "Use Trusted Connection" default setting

Tags: excel, odbc, ms-query

Couple of years using this site is as an invaluable resource, but first time posting.

I am having a little trouble with external data connections in Excel, specifically connecting to SQL Server through Microsoft Query.

Whenever I click

```
[Get External Data > 
     From Other Sources > 
          From Microsoft Query > 
               Choose Data Source: SQL Server]
```

it takes about 20 seconds before an error pops up:

[Error 18452 Login Failed Untrusted Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdKOx.png)

After I click OK a SQL Server Login dialog box pops up with "Use Trusted Connection" pre-checked. Each time I create a new data connection in Excel (I do this dozens of times per project), I have to uncheck that box and enter a login ID/pw instead for it to work. Add all those 20 seconds up and it's actually a pretty big annoyance for the type of work I do.

My question: how do I change the connection properties to where "Use Trusted Connection" is *unchecked* by default and the Login ID and Password fields are pre-filled?

Here is what the connection string portion of the HTML code looks like when I right-click the appropriate .odc file in [Documents > My Data Sources] and click 'edit in notepad':

```
<odc:ConnectionString>Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx_xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx;Data Source=XX.XX.XX.XX;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=XXXXXXX;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=Data_Warehouse</odc:ConnectionString>
```

I did look through the archives and found a few related discussions but none that addressed this question specifically. Thanks for your help. Please excuse any incorrect use of syntax and I hope I explained things clearly enough for a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

As luck would have it, only after spending a bit of time researching and asking the question did I figure out the embarassingly simple answer...

The login selection defaults to whatever was chose when the connection was first created. All I had to do was create a new connection and enter the credentials with "Use Trusted Connection" unchecked. I set the original connection up in Excel almost 2 years ago when I first joined my company and must have left "Use Trusted Connection" checked without really knowing what I was doing. Which is the reason why the error kept popping up after the connection initialized and failed, at which point I had to uncheck the box and try again. Silly me. #smh