# Storing password in Excel Mac 2016 ODBC connections using embedded Microsoft Query

Tags: excel, macos, odbc

I'm bulding an Excel Mac 2016 file that uses several connections to SQL Server using the embedded Microsoft Query service. The problem is that I'm unable to store the password in the connection: every time I open the file Excel asks for the password of every connection although it is always the same (and now I have 8 connections). No checkbox or option is displayed to store the password.

I've checked every option in the menus but I've been unable to find this feature. Also, I've tried to edit the connection string and adding ";PWD=" or ";Password=" but no luck. It seems to me that the login data and the queries should be separated but they are not.

It seems there are differences between the Mac and Windows version of Excel. Maybe this is not possible with Mac. A similar post refers to a "Use Trusted Connection" option but I can't see this on Mac.

[Excel - Microsoft Query - SQL Server login - "Use Trusted Connection" default setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868016/excel-microsoft-query-sql-server-login-use-trusted-connection-default-se)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Usually trying a few different connection strings you can find one that works for you. I tend to define username and password in the connection string but store them as environment variables so they can't be taken directly from the code ( dbUsername = Environ("LiveUsername")  dbPassword = Environ("LivePassword") ) for example. [SQL Server Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). Unfortunately I do not use Macs so sorry I cannot be of any more help...

Answer (score 1):

It won't let me add a comment, so I'm going to add an answer. I have Excel 2016 in Windows and there is a [save password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYTsB.jpg) checkbox just below the connection string. I have done several microsoft queries with the embedded service and I've also setup a connection with system DSNs. Strange to me that you're missing that simple checkbox just because you're on Mac. If you have the checkbox, click it and then save the file. The next time you open it, it shouldn't ask for your password again. Sorry if this is completely useless. :-/